# What is causing my professor to get an exception when she runs my program but it works fine on my computer?

Tags: java

I made a Hangman game which consists of 2 classes, a WordList class to pick the word to be guessed and a class with GUI called HangmanComplete.
This is my WordList class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordList {
    private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();

    public WordList(String wordlistFileName) {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(wordlistFileName));  
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine().trim();
                if (line.length() <= 0) continue;
                this.words.add(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't read list of words from " + wordlistFileName);
        }
    }

    public int getWordCount() {
        return this.words.size();
    }

    public String getWord(int index) {
        return this.words.get(index);
    }

    public String removeWord(int index) {
        return this.words.remove(index);
    }
}
```

I do not get any compile time errors. And here is the code for the entire program: [GitHub](https://github.com/xson555/HangmanComplete/tree/master)

When my professor runs it, she gets this error:

> jGRASP exec: java HangmanComplete ---- at: Nov 6, 2015 9:29:26 PM ----jGRASP wedge: pid for process is 610 pids for wedge are 608 and 609. ----jGRASP wedge: CLASSPATH is ":.:::/Applications/jGRASP.app/Contents/Resources/jgrasp/extensions/classes". ----jGRASP wedge: working directory is /Users/MauraDeek/Downloads ----jGRASP wedge2: actual command sent [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java HangmanComplete]. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't read list of words from wordlist.txt at WordList.(WordList.java:22) at HangmanComplete.(HangmanComplete.java:56) at HangmanComplete.main(HangmanComplete.java:122) ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1. ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: You shouldnt be throwing a new exception after one has been thrown. Ideally you would like to know what caused the exception, so you should print e.printStackTrace()

Comment: You've made a common mistake of hiding the IOException. Change your IAE constructor to pass the IOException as the second parameter.  Then, the stack trace will show a "Root cause" when your professor runs it, which will provide more information about what happened.  Most likely, it simply couldn't find that file you're trying to open.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr how can I do this?

Comment: Your IllegalArgumentException constructor call is passing a single parameter.  You have to add a second parameter, the "e", being the IOException.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the solution to your question. You should place your **"wordlist.txt"** file inside project not inside your source package. I have tried placing with source file(.java) i got similar exception but when tried placing it inside Project its running fine.

Please find the below project structure.

[Project Strucure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV3t1.jpg)

Comment: Could you please show me how you had your code in order for it to run properly? @Prakash Thete

Comment: I have not done any changes to code. Just place your wordlist file inside project not inside src package

Comment: In jgrasp, I created a project which contained source files for HangmanComplete.java and WordList.java. I just added to this list wordlist.txt. Is this what you mean? @Prakash Thete

Comment: Just copy- > paste it from src package and place it inside your project which you created in jgrasp (i.e. I mean place it outside of src package)

Comment: where exactly is source package? Thats where my confusion is

Comment: I have added project structure i created in answer please have a look at it.